# Calculating with ascii maps in Netlogo

Tags: ascii, gis, netlogo

I have two ASCII files that contain cell values from a raster grid (map1 & map2). Is it possible in Netlogo to create a third map (map3) by calculating the cell values of map1 with those of map2? (like some kind of raster overlay or raster calculator). The output map (map3) would be a product of the first 2 maps.

So when calculating the average: if a particular cell has a value 1 in map1, and value 3 in map2, it will have a value 2 in map3.

This is the code until now:

```
    extensions [ gis ]
    globals [map1 map2]
    patches-own [mapo1 mapo2]

    to setup
      ca
      load-map
      draw
    end

    to load-map
      ; Load the dataset
      set map1 gis:load-dataset "C://uses/finalnim.asc"
      set map2 gis:load-dataset "C://uses/finalvlak.asc"
       gis:apply-raster map1 mapo1
      gis:apply-raster map2 mapo2


      gis:set-world-envelope-ds [155000 180040  418750 437550]
    end


    to draw
      gis:set-drawing-color white
      ask patches [
        if mapo1 = 0.9 [ set pcolor Green ]
        if mapo1 = 0.7 [ set pcolor blue ]
        if mapo1 = 0.3 [ set pcolor orange ]
        if mapo1 = 0.2 [ set pcolor red ]


      ]
      resize-world 0 313 0 235
        set-patch-size 1

    end
```

Comment: No, it is not clear at all what you need. Describe it better.

Comment: Thank you for your response, I edited the description of my question.